# How does ThreadPoolExecutor assigns a thread from the ThreadPool?

Tags: java, threadpool, executorservice

I have been trying to find on what basis are threads from the existing threadpool are used.

As an example, we have following executor:

```
    ThreadPoolExecutor executor;
    executor = (ThreadPoolExecutor) Executors
            .newFixedThreadPool(30);
    executor.setKeepAliveTime(60L, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    executor.allowCoreThreadTimeOut(true);
```

There can be a maximum of 30 threads in the pool. What will happen if we:

1. Submit 30 runnable tasks.
2. Once those are complete we submit 10 more runnable tasks.

In the step 1, lets further assume that the tasks were submitted at 12:00:00 and at 12:00:01, all 30 threads were executing. By 12:00:05, 10 threads (assuming T1 to T10) completed executing their respective runnable tasks. Rest of the threads completed by 12:00:10.

Now if no more tasks were to be submitted, threads T1 to T10 were to be terminated by 12:01:05 while the rest would be terminated by 12:01:10.

But if in step 2, if I submitted 10 more tasks at time 12:00:15, to which threads from the threadpool do these tasks get allocated to?

1. Random?
2. Threads that have remained idle most of the time?
3. Threads that most recently became idle?

Comment: I suppose it somewhat depends on the `BlockingQueue` implementation used and whether or not its internal synchronization is fair. But mentallurg is correct; if you really want to understand the implementation then you should look at the implementation. The source of `ThreadPoolExecutor` is well commented. From an API perspective, however, which thread is chosen is not specified by `ExecutorService` nor `ThreadPoolExecutor` (though the latter does document under what conditions a _new_ thread may be used).

Comment: @SahilJain: Describing what your have done to resolve the problem or to answer the question helps others to understand what is clear to you, what is not, and how detailed should the answer be. Such description show also respect to the people who would answer it because it helps to save their time. Thus, please put information from your comment to the OP and delete the comment. The goal of comments is to adjust questions and answer so that comments can be deleted at any time and Q. and A. remain still useful to anyone.